# Image shifts to the right in wordpress post

Tags: image, wordpress

Setting up contact information.
Inserted text first and then, started inserting images right before it. First two display perfectly the way i need them. 3rd one (with the envelope) shifts to the right. Can't understand what's happening with it. 
Had anyone ever come across something like that?

Live link here
It's at the bottom of the page
http://soloveich.com/pr6/

Comment: If you remove `margin: 0 1em 1em 0;` from `img.alignleft` in the css, then the three images will line up.

Comment: Cool (could you mark it as the cost answer if it helped you)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to remove

```
margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
```

from `img.alignleft` in the css, then the three images will line up.